# Always print header before output in Hive QL

Tags: hive, hiveql

I run lots of Hive queries everyday, and I have to write `SET hive.cli.print.header = TRUE;` at the beginning of each one every time. Is there a config file I could edit so printing the header would be the default behavior ?

If it is not possible, is there a reason for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this thread

[HIve: writing column headers to local file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656899/hive-writing-column-headers-to-local-file)

One answer says to put the set statement in .hiverc in your home directory.

Comment: I have a `.hivehistory` file and a `hivelog` directory, but no such file; should I create it ?

Comment: Yup, if it doesn't exist just create it.

Comment: @M.Massias: Some more information for `.hiverc`: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Cli#LanguageManualCli-ThehivercFile