# How to export a Hive table into a CSV file including header?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I used this Hive query to export a table into a CSV file.

```
hive -f mysql.sql

row format delimited fields terminated by ','
select * from Mydatabase,Mytable limit 100"

cat /LocalPath/* > /LocalPath/table.csv
```

However, it does not include table column names.
How to export in csv the column names ?

```
show tablename ?
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hive: writing column headers to local file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656899/hive-writing-column-headers-to-local-file)

Answer (score 4):

You should add `set hive.cli.print.header=true;` before your select query to get column names as the first row of your output. The output would look as `Mytable.col1, Mytable.col2 ...`.

If you don't want the table name with the column names, use `set hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names=false;`. The first row of your output would then look like `col1, col2 ...`

Comment: Please state clearly what you are trying to achieve. I believe `insert overwrite` is used for writing to a hive table. In that case the column names must be defined in the table schema. My answer would work only in case you are exporting data using a `select` query.

Answer (score 0):

Invoking hive command-line with the parameters suggested in the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50160264/2438951) here works for a plain select. So, you can extract the column names and create the csv to start with, as follows:

```
hive -S --hiveconf hive.cli.print.header=true --hiveconf hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names=false --database Mydatabase -e 'select * from Mytable limit 0;' > /LocalPath/table.csv
```

Post which you can have the actual data extraction part run, except this time, remember to append to the csv:

`cat /LocalPath/* >> /LocalPath/table.csv   ## From your question with >> for append`